# Building a single product for multiple environments with Tycho

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho, p2

How do I create a platform-independent product with merged environment dependencies?

When using Tycho 0.19.0 with eclipse-application packaging type, [separateEnvironments](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/product-export-mojo.html#separateEnvironments) parameter of `tycho-packaging-plugin` can be used to prevent creation of multiple product distributions for each platform (a single, universal distribuition is produced).

```
 <packaging>eclipse-application</packaging>
 <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>${tycho-groupid}</groupId>
       <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${tycho-version}</version>
       <configuration>
         <separateEnvironments>false</separateEnvironments>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </build>
```

But Tycho warns:

```
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.19.0:product-export (default) @ q7runner ---
[WARNING] The packaging type 'eclipse-application' is deprecated; use 'eclipse-repository' instead. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho_Messages_Explained#Eclipse_Application
```

Same warning appears when I try using tycho-packaging directly.

With `eclipse-repository` packaging type and direct invocation of `tycho-p2-director` plugin `separateEnvironments` seem to be ineffective:

```
<packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
<plugin>
  <groupId>${tycho-groupid}</groupId>
  <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${tycho-version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>create-distributions</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>materialize-products</goal>
        <goal>archive-products</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <separateEnvironments>false</separateEnvironments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
..................
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.19.0:materialize-products (create-distributions) @ q7runner ---
[INFO] Installing product com.xored.q7.q7runner for environment win32/win32/x86 to C:\Users\vasili\git\q7\runner\product\target\products\com.xored.q7.q7run
ner\win32\win32\x86
Installing com.xored.q7.q7runner 1.3.12.201406101420.
Operation completed in 35268 ms.
[INFO] Installing product com.xored.q7.q7runner for environment win32/win32/x86_64 to C:\Users\vasili\git\q7\runner\product\target\products\com.xored.q7.q7
runner\win32\win32\x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tycho-p2-director-plugin` delegates the creation of the product installations to the p2 director, so that the resulting installations can be updated with p2. (This is something that you won't be able to do with an installation created by `eclipse-application`). Unfortunately, the [p2 director doesn't have support for multi-environment installations](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303490), and hence also Tycho's `eclipse-repository` doesn't have it.

Comment: It would make sense to post your requirements in the [Tycho issue tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi) to make sure they are considered in case `eclipse-application` should be deleted.